# Позиционирование элементов снизу контента

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы вкладки располагались снизу контента(section)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 https://jsfiddle.net/2rkjxyoj/

Comment: Сделайте рабочий пример на JSfiddle, тогда вам скорее помогут.

Answer (score 1):

Отправить label'ы вниз (в разметке), а инпуты оставить там, где они сейчас. При желании лейблы можно положить в дополнительный контейнер.